# Fixed footer hides when clicks on empty area

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I've a fixed footer (with a nav bar inside it) on my Jquery Mobile app. The problem i've is that when the user clicks/taps or similar on the app (empty area most likely) the footer hides.

It uses some kind animation (slide down) so i'm guessing isn't a bug, but something i'm missing with the data-* attributes to prevent this.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have the attribute `data-fullscreen="true"` applied.  This attribute will cause the behavior you describe by design.

Simply remove the attribute and keep your `data-position="fixed"` and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have a footer with a navbar too and mine doesn't hide on click. Try if this works for you:

```
<div data-role="footer" data-id="nav">      
            <div data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="top" data-position="fixed">
                <ul>
                    <li><a data-icon="grid" href="#one">One</a></li>
                    <li><a data-icon="grid" href="#two">Two</a></li>
                    <li><a data-icon="grid" href="#three">Three</a></li>
                    <li><a data-icon="grid" href="#four">Four</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /navbar -->
        </div><!-- /footer -->
```